# JavaScript runtime error: 'variable' is undefined while checking to see if undefined

Tags: javascript, html, inline

I have the following lines written with HTML and some inline JS:

```
 <% if (x !== undefined || x !== null) { %>
  <div> Foo </div>
 <% } %>
```

It produces this dynamic function code:

```
if (x !== undefined || x !== null) {...
```

As well as this error:

```
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'x' is undefined
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Check `typeof x == "undefined"` instead.

Comment: It happens because...`x` is not defined.  JS has few layers of this, but the error messages aren't always clear on the distinction `var x` _declares_ a variable and its _value_ is `undefined`. So, you'll be able to use it because "they exist", so to speak. Undeclared variables tend to throw errors such as the one you saw because you are trying to access something that doesn't exist (undeclared). Although `x = 5` will implicitly set a `window.x` in non-strict mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for Javascript to compare the value of the `x` variable it must look it up; since it is not yet defined it throws an error message.  This error is happening before the runtime even attempts to compare the value to `undefined`.  It's a little bit of a chicken-and-egg problem.

use `typeof x === 'undefined'` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're trying to access a variable that has never been defined.

Example:

```js
'use strict';
console.log(x);
```

You can check if a variable has been declared using the [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

```js
'use strict';
console.log(typeof x === 'undefined');
```

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure what syntax `<% [some javascript] %>` is (Classic ASP?), but as an alternative, sniff if `x` exists on your global object.

Since you've tagged this `html`, your global object should be `window`. (In node, as an example, the global object is literally `global`.)

```
<% if (window.x) { %>
  <div> Foo </div>
<% } %>
```

And you're done.

You could also use the more verbose, but also more precise, code I think you intended in your post, so that if `x` is falsy *but not `null` or `undefined`* -- eg, `0` or `""` -- it still trips the `if`.

Though **I'm pretty sure you wanted an `&&` in there, not an `||`**. That is, as originally written, your condition will always evaluate true. If `x` is `undefined`, then it's by definition not `null`, and vice versa!

Here's the tweaked version...

```
<% if (window.x !== undefined && window.x !== null) { %>
  <div> Foo </div>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

variable x is not defined in your javascript code. Do a check with typeof operator.

```
typeof x=="undefined"
```

if if returns true then your variable x is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<% if (!x) { %>
  <div> Foo </div>
<% } %>
```

`!x` will return true for an empty string, NaN, null, undefined.

Comment: That still doesn't work, though - if `x` is not declared _it throws an error if being looked up_.